Declaration of MWCallbackStream must be compatible with StreamInterface
This is an error following upgrade to Mediawiki 1.39.8 that appears in error logs whenever a page with an image is visited or when trying to upload a file (resulting in browser Error 500).
Declaration of MWCallbackStream::write($string) must be compatible with Psr\Http\Message\StreamInterface::write(string $string): int in ..includes/http/MWCallbackStream.php on line 49

Here is that file
Edit: Seems that the culprit was the Data Transfer extension...
